Github Actions Workflow fails with lfs:true
I am trying to run a Github Actions Workflow with Git Large File Storage set to True. But the task and the pipeline fails even though I have installed Git and Git LFS on the runner and they have been added to path as well.
username@vmname:~$ git version
git version 2.25.1
username@vmname:~$ git-lfs version
git-lfs/3.5.1 (Github; Linux amd64; go 1.21.8)
username@vmname:~$ whereis git
git: /usr/bin/git /usr/share/man/man1/git.1.gz
username@vmname:~$ whereis git-lfs
git-lfs: /usr/bin/git-lfs /usr/share/man/man1/git-lfs.1.gz

Workflow file:
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: {self_hosted_runner_name}

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
        with:
          lfs: true

Error: Unable to locate executable file: git-lfs. Please verify either the file path exists or the file can be found within a directory specified by the PATH environment variable. Also check the file mode to verify the file is executable
When I run the same without lfs:true, it is able to checkout the code successfully and I dont see any issue.
But when sudo apt-get install -y git-lfs is added to a task, then it runs successfully as it doesnt complain about the path.
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: {self_hosted_runner_name}

  - name: Install Packages
    shell: bash
    run: |
      sudo apt update
      sudo apt-get install -y git-lfs

  - uses: actions/checkout@v4
    with:
      lfs: true

Could anyone please let me know how to resolve the issue without adding sudo apt-get install -y git-lfs to a task and still make the task to pick up git and git-lfs path automatically?
Edit:
After adding Git-lfs to the PATH https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions?tool=bash#adding-a-system-path, I do get the same error as earlier
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: {self_hosted_runner_name}

  - name: Add Git-LFS to Github Path
    run: echo "/usr/bin/git-lfs" >> $GITHUB_PATH

  - uses: actions/checkout@v4
    with:
      lfs: true

As mentioned by @Azeem tried,
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: {self_hosted_runner_name}

  - name: Add Git-LFS to Github Path
    run: |
      echo "/usr/bin/git-lfs" >> $GITHUB_PATH
      ls -l /usr/bin/git-lfs

  #- uses: actions/checkout@v4
  #  with:
  #    lfs: true

I am getting ls: cannot access '/usr/bin/git-lfs': No such file or directory. Error: Process completed with exit code 2.
sudo apt-get update and sudo apt-get install -y git-lfs, technically doesnt install but rather sets/updates the packages
Logs:











echo $PATH gives /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors. Is it happening on ubuntu-latest or on your self-hosted runner? Did you verify it with whereis git-lfs in your workflow? Did you try setting PATH in your workflow?

There's more than one way to set PATH, you probably picked the wrong one.

@Azeem Even adding echo "/usr/bin/git-lfs" >> $GITHUB_PATH to the workflow, I still get the same error

Run ls -l /usr/bin/git-lfs before your checkout step and share the output. Also, when you're installing it with apt-get, why are you using shell: bash?

@Azeem. As mentioned added before checkout step    run: |       echo "/usr/bin/git-lfs" >> $GITHUB_PATH       ls -l /usr/bin/git-lfs
And I am getting ls: cannot access '/usr/bin/git-lfs': No such file or directory. Error: Process completed with exit code 2.

git-lfs doesn't seem to be installed. You need to verify it.

It is already installed. Please see the git version and git-lfs version at the top. The issue is, it is not picking up without explicitly specifying to install it again as a github task

When it's installed via apt-get, do you see it skipping installation due to the already installed one in the logs? Please add those logs in your question as well. The output of ls -l shows that it doesn't exist so that needs to be fixed. You can echo $PATH to see if /usr/bin is in there or not which usually is added already.

WIthout adding sudo apt update to the task before installing It says E: unable to locate package git-lfs. Building dependency tree.... Reading State Information.. Error: Process completed with exit code 100

With adding sudo apt update and sudo apt-get install -y git-lfs, it technically doesnt install rather sets up the packages. Please see the latest edit above

echo $PATH gives /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

/usr/bin is already added in PATH. The apt install logs are not complete. Those setting up logs are the last lines only. Please include its complete logs. The packages to be installed should be listed under "The following NEW packages will be installed:" line.

I have added detailed logs at the top. Please check

Did you restart the agent process? It doesn't magically pick up changes to the PATH. You may need to also change the permissions on git-lfs. Ideally git LFS is installed on the agent and not from any workflow at all. Also try using the same script as used by GitHub to provision their runner: https://github.com/actions/runner-images/blob/main/images/ubuntu/scripts/build/install-git-lfs.sh
